# Redirecting icmp traffic through one gateway and tcp through another

Tags: default, routes, gateway, icmp

I have two devices connected to a network, but I am trying to create my own little network. I want to route my icmp traffic of client, say 10.10.10.99 through 10.10.10.50 and all the other traffic of 10.10.10.99 should remain unaffected and pass via default gateway.

I was able to route the whole traffic by changing the default gateway, but I no longer want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible in `Linux` through the usage of `ip route add` for adding a new table with the new gateway and `iptables` to mark certain packets destined for a `specific port`. The new table can then act on the marked packets.

There is a good example for how to achieve this at this [link on tldp](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.netfilter.html)

For example you can do the following for marking/routing ICMP traffic :

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -t mangle -p icmp -j MARK --set-mark 1
# create a table icmp.out to handle all icmp traffic
echo 201 icmp.out >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add fwmark 1 table icmp.out
ip route add default via <gateway> dev <dev> table icmp.out
```

Comment: Can you please explain in this in detail? I am a newbie.